# Why cooling an exothermic solution it increases it's solubility?

Tags: solubility

In my chemistry book writes that cooling an exothermic solution(e.g. $\ce{NaOH + H2O}$) increases it's solubility, and I can't understand why since the cooling should decrease it.

Comment: Why do you think cooling should decrease the solubility?

Comment: Tables of solubility

Comment: Can you expand upon that? Perhaps with a reference

Comment: ''Solubility of liquids and solids increases as the temperature raises ' - this is from the class book we use in Romania. I think solubility increases with temperature because there is need for heat for hydration of ions. And also, if the temperature is bigger, than the agitation of molecules should be bigger, and the process of diffusion should be faster ... I'm not a native english speaker, sorry.

Comment: See the linked question for an answer